# Prevent javascript function

Tags: javascript, .net, vb.net

I am using a webbrowser inside VB.net

```
webbrowser1.navigation("MYAWESOMEURL")
```

MYAWESOMEURL has a javascript function being called inside an iframe.. Here is what the source code looks like

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="MYANNOYINGCLASS.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
    blah blah ah annoyin stuff
      <iframe id="content" src="about:blank" frameborder="0" style="display:none;"></iframe>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            ANNOYINGCLASS.ANNOYINGFUNCTION(); //Defined in the script src
        </script>
    blah blah blah annoyin stuff
    </body>
</html>
```

I hope this helps others too! i am absolutely stumped.

Comment: can you pass a url parameter in MYAWESOMEURL?  And can you add code into the iframe?  I take it you do not want ANNOYINGCLASS.ANNOYINGFUNCTION(); called?

Comment: Corrent i do not want ANNOYINGCLASS.ANNOYINGFUNCTION() to be called. I can not pass any parameters into the url or the iframe. I have to access to the actual code.

Comment: But i have found that ANNOYINGCLASS.ANNOYINGFUNCION() checks to see if   ANNOYINGCLASS.ANNOYINGVARIABLE returns true. Perhaps injecting a call to make the variable true before ANNOYINGCLASS.ANNOYINGFUNCTION is called would work?

Comment: I do not understand here...which code is the iframe code, which code is being called in myawesomeurl?  If you have access to the source code can you just comment out the function call?

Comment: I do not have access to the source code. The entire document is accessed via the url.